# is that possible to execute sql query on vb.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net

```
ALTER DATABASE test SET ENABLE_BROKER
```

this is the sql query i wish to execute while program is executing..
because i do not want to everytime i change computer also need open sql management tool to execute this query rath

Comment: Read up on ADO.NET commands. After you set the command text, execute .ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can fire `alter database` like a regular SQL statement:

```
Dim connection As SqlConnection
connection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=myServerAddress;" & _
    "Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;")
Dim command As SqlCommand
command = connection.CreateCommand()
command.CommandText = "ALTER DATABASE test SET ENABLE_BROKER"
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never. Missing opening and closing of the connection. In case anyone needs it:

```
Dim connection As SqlConnection
connection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=myServerAddress;" & _
    "Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;")
connection.Open()
Dim command As SqlCommand
command = connection.CreateCommand()
command.CommandText = "ALTER DATABASE test SET ENABLE_BROKER"
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
connection.Close()
```